# Embedded parentheses giving the error: ! Missing { inserted.

Tags: errors

I'm getting the above error and I can't figure out why. Here's the offending code.

```
t\left(2^\left(m+1\right) \right)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just passing the token `\left` to the superscript, you need to pass it the whole sub-expression using a `{ }` group:

```
$t\left(2^{\left(m+1\right) }\right) $
```

[image]

Comment: The solution certainly makes sense. Could someone explain to me what the error message means? Is it saying that TeX detected a problem because the argument to `^` was merely `\left`, and somehow it knew that was wrong? So TeX went ahead and inserted a `{` there, but didn't know where to put the `}`? I guess the "inserted" part of the error message is what confuses me the most. Why would TeX bother to insert a `{` if it's just going to fail with a fatal error anyway?

Comment: @LarsH your description is correct,apart from the fact that errors are not fatal you have the chance to interact with them as you go along. For example you can respond `i}` to insert a matching close brace and the document will then complete without further error.

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if it was something of that sort. We don't use that kind of model much these days, do we? I mean, where the processor runs into an error, and can't continue as is, but allows you to intervene, and then it can keep going without starting over.

Comment: @LarsH No but when it was taking 15 minutes per page, getting to the end and then fixing as many errors as possible before starting over was a big win.

Comment: Those were the days!